# Update column from another table column value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to update user_id column on comments table from comment_users table user_id column value whhich comment_id matches on comments table id columns.

**comment_users table**

```
id: 5 comment_id: 1, user_id: 20
```

**comments table**
before

```
id:1 user_id: NULL
```

after

```
id: 1 user_id: 20
```

I executed sql below but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE comments
  SET user_id = comment_users.user_id
  INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
  WHERE comment_users.comment_id = comments.id


Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comment' at line 3:       UPDATE comments
      SET user_id = comment_users.user_id
      INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
      WHERE comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
```

I have no idea about what is wrong.

Comment: which table is your user_id in SET command coming from?

Comment: Try this , UPDATE comments INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comments.id 
  SET user_id = comment_users.user_id

Comment: @FahadAnjum It doesn't work since the user_id after SET column is ambiguous, but it works to change comments.user_id ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `update join` syntax is wrong, try following:

```
UPDATE comments
INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
SET comments.user_id = comment_users.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the table name for comments?

```
UPDATE comments
SET user_id = comment_users.user_id
FROM [table_name] comments
INNER JOIN comment_users ON comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
WHERE comment_users.comment_id = comments.id
```